# Running statistical operations across variables in a dataframe using R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, time-series, regression

I currently have a time series that I need to regress against several variables of different lengths. I need to perform a couple of statistical operations on them and I am trying to find the most efficient way to do so.

Example- I have three independent time series variables B, C, D and a dependent variable A.

> `Data# A tibble: 15 × 5
>            Date`A B C `D
>          <dttm>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
>   1  2017-10-01  0.03000  0.050 -0.070 -0.014
>   2  2017-09-01  0.02500  0.010 -0.050  0.040
>   3  2017-08-01 -0.02000 -0.070  0.010  0.024
>   4  2017-07-01  0.01500 -0.004  0.030 -0.010
>   5  2017-06-01  0.00800 -0.007  0.050  0.064
>   6  2017-05-01  0.04000  0.040  0.054  0.010
>   7  2017-04-01  0.06000  0.050  0.068  0.080
>   8  2017-03-01  0.00114  0.004  0.012  0.040
>   9  2017-02-01  0.00058 -0.090  0.032  0.050
>   10 2017-01-01 -0.00054  0.040  0.040  0.090
>   11 2016-12-01  0.06000  0.060     NA  0.010
>   12 2016-11-01  0.00400  0.010     NA     NA
>   13 2016-10-01 -0.03000  0.020     NA     NA
>   14 2016-09-01 -0.04000     NA     NA     NA
>   15 2016-08-01  0.08000     NA     NA     NA`

I'd like to create 12 more lagged variables by lagging the variables B, C, D by one period each (i.e Blag1, Clag1, Dlag1, Blag2, clag2....)

Once I have created the 12 lagged variables, I'd like to run a regression b/w A and the 15 variables (B,C,D and the 12 lagged variables)

I am currently lagging the variables in excel and then running a regression in R. The lag doesn't work as intended in R due to the NAs.

What's the most efficient way to run these (lag & regression) operations in R?

[Lags in Excel:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wouYY.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by 'efficient'? It runs fast? It minimizes the number of lines of code written?  It's easy for others to understand what your code does?

Comment: Minimizes the number of lines of code. Thanks

Comment: Minimizes the number of lines of code. I am unable to come up with a code that can perform the required number of lags on the variables B,C, and D at once without having to adjust them individually. The N/As create a challenge too in the sense the lag function takes them into account and lags them too whereas they need to be ignore.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go.

```R
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1001)
df = data_frame(Date = as.Date(seq(17440,17014,length.out=15),origin="1970-01-01"),
                A = runif(15,-.1,.1),
                B = runif(15,-.1,.1),
                C = runif(15,-.1,.1),
                D = runif(15,-.1,.1)
)

df$B[14:15] = NA
df$C[11:15] = NA
df$D[12:15] = NA

genLag = function(df,col,lag){
  `[[`(df,paste0(col,"lag",lag)) = lead(`[[`(df,col),lag)
  assign("df",df,envir = globalenv())
}
for(col in LETTERS[2:4]){
  for(lag in 1:4){
    genLag(df,col,lag)
  }
}

model = lm(A~.,data=df[,names(df) != "Date"])
```

I had to generate some dummy data to match what you had, at least close.  Note I added the NA's the end of the columns like you have.

First, you don't want to *lag* your data, you want to *lead* your data.  Lagging takes x[t-1] and puts it in x[t].  However, because you data is in descending data order you need to put x[t+1] into x[t].  Data formatting is important.

Second, I don't see how doing the lag/lead work in Excel prevents the NA's from happening in R - those empty cells are still going to load in as NAs.

I wrote a function called `genLag` which takes as arguments your data.frame, the column you want to lag and how far you want to lag it.  This will create a new column in the data.frame which is named something like `Blag1`.  Then it assigns it back to the global environment, one giant side effect.

A couple of nested `for` loops to iterate over the column names and the lag distances and we have in 9 lines of code the creation of 12 new columns.

Finally, fitting the model is really easy.  In a formula statement you can use `.` to mean 'all other columns in the data'.  So, `lm(A~.,data=df)` will regress A against all 16 other columns.  Which is bad, you only want 15 columns - we need to drop the 'Date' column to make sure we don't have a 1:1 model situation.

The final model that is produced is utter garbage.  You only have 6 complete observations so you only have 5 degrees of freedom meaning 10 of your inputs are singularities.  I hope you have more real data in your dataset.